When increasing the frequency of an induction motor can't I just add a capacitor to maintain torque instead of increasing the voltage?
When increasing the speed of an induction motor if one wants to maintain the same torque, the voltage has to be increased at the same proportion as the frequency of the AC supply.
This is because the inductive reactance of the windings in the stator increases with the increase in frequency (inductive reactance=2×pi×frequency×inductance).
If the voltage was not increased the magnetizing current in the stator windings would reduce, hence there would be a reduction in torque (because I = V/Z).
What if, when I increase the frequency, I just added a capacitor to each 3 phase line, at the right capacitance value to cancel out the increase in inductive reactance?
Wouldn't that negate me needing to increase the voltage because the impedance hasn't increased?

Yes, that'll work. The capacitors will resonate with the motor's inductance, thereby increasing the voltage provided to the motor.
